# Upgrading from Cocos2D 0.99.5 to 2.1 resulting in 3 errors

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, upgrade

I was attempting to upgrade Cocos2D in my existing project resulting in issues no one knew how to solve, so I decided to start with fresh project then migrate my files over. I'm not sure when this happened but now I have 3 errors:

**1.)** Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found

**2.)** ld: file not found: /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_cocos2d_proj-atnaeyeebjlopnbgbcqjaoeylldh/Build/Intermediates/test cocos2d proj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test cocos2d proj.build/Objects-normal/i386/cocos2d_libraryTests.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**3.)** error: unable to open executable '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_cocos2d_proj-atnaeyeebjlopnbgbcqjaoeylldh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test cocos2d proj.app/test cocos2d proj'

Comment: 3 is a result of 2, 2 may be caused by 1. I suppose 1 means search for any uses of XCTest.h and consider whether this header needs to be imported, or whether the file importing the header really needs to be compiled.

Comment: I have, but when I get rid of it I get 19 errors. Bunch of Macho-O Linker Errors like "_hmGLFreeAll" referenced from _ccGLInvalidateStateCache in ccGLStateCache.o, etc.

Comment: I re-added the Kazmath folder as a TAN folder, not blue, as well as the src folder. I originally added it as a blue folder to get rid of another error. It finally compiles, but have a ton of Mac-O Linker warnings which I'll have to figure out. Back to the original problem with sprites positions and collisions with sprites/tiles being offset.